# Rig doesn't work on imported model

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, pose-mode, auto-rig-pro

I rigged a model in blender but when I want to pose it nothing happens please help me.
I have uploaded the blender file on Google drive here's the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vhHSbjj3sJaEUbtYu-G0vxmd_5lTzlCR/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your object is a bit too small, deparent it (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*, scale up both the object and the armature (like x 5), parent *With Automatic Weight* again and it works.